# Accessing button in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Carousel of items, in which i have a button that I respectively want to be able to make a Clicked eventhandler on, and as well be able to send my binding to the code behind.

The button is supposed to link to a webpage, depending on the item shown in the carousel.

Unfortunately, since I have multiple objects that i append to my bindingcontext, I am not able to make a unique eventhandler on my button i.e. giving it an `x:name` and a `GestureRecognizer`.

The code is as follows:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding .}" >
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Button x:Name="btn12" Text="Read more" BackgroundColor="#105F73" Command="{Binding Link}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Optimally, I want to give the button a tapped eventhandler and pass its "command" to the eventhandler in which a webpage is opened:

```
private void btn12_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: GET LINK AND REDIRECT 
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri(link));
}
```

Naturally, It doesn't work, as the `bindingcontext` constructs multiple buttons. Additionally, I don't know if it is correct to pass the binding through a `command`.

To summarize, how do i construct a button onclicked eventhandler in the following scenario, and how do i pass the Binding to the eventhandler?

Answer (score 0):

You can use commandparameter

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <Button Command="{x:Static local:MyPageName.MyButton_Click}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

and then

```
public static Command MyButton_Click = new Command ( (object item) => {
            var myItem = item as MyItem;
            // Do something with myItem...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, give a x:name to the content Page that you are using:-

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject;assembly= MyProject"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyPage"
             x:Name="ThisPage">
```

And then give Source to the Command. Like this. This method will call the Command that is there in the ViewModel of the Current Page. Also, you can use a Command Parameter to know which Item has Triggered the Command.

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding .}" >
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Button x:Name="btn12" Text="Read more" BackgroundColor="#105F73" Command="{Binding Link, Source={x:Reference Name=ThisPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"}/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```